# Make tuples of a list include alphabet ordered number, alphabet, counts

Tags: python, list

I have a list includes small lowercase:

```
l = ['a','z','y','y','z','y','b','b']
```

How to make a tuple-list like as below:

```
[(1, 'a', 1), (2, 'b', 2), (25, 'y', 3), (26, 'z', 2)]
```

I attempt to invoke `Counter` to count alphabets of my list, but I don't know how to next to do.

```
from collections import Counter

l = ['a','z','y','y','z','y','b','b']

c = Counter(l)
# [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('y', 3), ('z', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommand you invoke `ascii_lowercase` of `string`. It has ready-made lowercase includes `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`

This is my method:

```
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_lowercase

l = ['a','z','y','y','z','y','b','b']

c = Counter(l)

sorted_items = sorted(c.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])

# get result when you need ordinal number of lowcase
print [ (ascii_lowercase.index(k)+1, k, v) for k, v in sorted_items]
# [(1, 'a', 1), (2, 'b', 2), (25, 'y', 3), (26, 'z', 2)]
```

If you want to get differet result in your first element of tuple, I teach you some tricks

```
# get result when you need ordinal number of count in decreasing order
print [ (index, item[0], item[1]) for index, item in enumerate(c.most_common(),1)]
# [(1, 'y', 3), (2, 'z', 2), (3, 'b', 2), (4, 'a', 1)]


# get result when you need ordinal number of count in increasing order
print [ (index, item[0], item[1]) for index, item in enumerate(sorted(c.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]),1)]
# [(1, 'a', 1), (2, 'z', 2), (3, 'b', 2), (4, 'y', 3)]
```

It can do more interesting result, right?

Answer (score 5):

One way to get the ordinal number of a letter is to call the `ord` function on it, and compare it to the result of calling `ord('a')`. For example:

```
>>> ord('s')
115
>>> ord('a')
97
>>> ord('s') - ord('a') + 1
19
```

Another way is to build a mapping and just reference it:

```
>>> import string
>>> ordinals = {letter: ordinal 
                for ordinal, letter in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, 1)}
>>> ordinals['s']
19
```

Either way, once you've got the ordinals, merging them in with the `Counter` counts is easy:

```
>>> l = ['a','z','y','y','z','y','b','b']
>>> c = Counter(l)
>>> [(ordinals[letter], letter, count) for letter, count in c.items()]
[(25, 'y', 3), (1, 'a', 1), (26, 'z', 2), (2, 'b', 2)]
```

And, if you want that sorted by the ordinal, the default sort order for tuples looks at the elements in lexicographical order—in other words, `(1, <anything>)` comes before `(2, <anything>)`, and so on. So:

```
>>> sorted((ordinals[letter], letter, count) for letter, count in c.items())
[(1, 'a', 1), (2, 'b', 2), (25, 'y', 3), (26, 'z', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
r = []
for i in c:
    r.append(((ord(i) - ord('a') + 1), i, c[i]),)
r.sorted()
print r
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter
In[10] : l = ['a','z','y','y','z','y','b','b']
In[11] : result = [(ord(k)-96,k,v) for k,v in Counter(l).iteritems()] #ord('a') = 97
In[12] : sorted(result,key=lambda x: x[1])
Out[12] :
[(1, 'a', 1), (2, 'b', 2), (25, 'y', 3), (26, 'z', 2)]
```